# R for loop: creating data frames using split?

Tags: r, list, loops, for-loop, split

I have data that I want to separate by date, I have managed to do this manually through:

```
tsssplit <- split(tss, tss$created_at)
```

and then creating dataframes for each list which I then use.

```
t1 <- tsssplit[[1]]

t2 <- tsssplit[[2]]
```

But I don't know how many splits I will need, as sometimes the og data frame may may have 6 dates to split up by, and sometimes it may have 5, etc. So I want to create a for loop.

Within the for loop, I want to incorporate this code, which connects to a function:

```
bscore3 <- score.sentiment(t3$cleaned_text,pos.words,neg.words,.progress='text')
score3 <- as.integer(bscore3$score[[1]])
```

Then I want to be able to create a new data frame that has the scores for each list.

So essentially I want the for loop to:

1. split the data into lists using split
2. split each list into a separate data frames for each different day
3. Come out with a score for each data frame
4. Put that into a new data frame

It doesn't have to be exactly like this as long as I can come up with a visualisation of the scores at the end.

Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you keep the data as a list of frames, and use `lapply(tsssplit, function(x) ...)` instead of a `for` loop. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/3358227

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not recommended to create separate dataframes in the global environment, they are difficult to keep track of. Put them in a list instead. You have started off well by using `split` and creating list of dataframes. You can then iterate over each dataframe in the list and apply the function on each one of them.

Using `by` this would look like as :

```
by(tss, tss$created_at, function(x) {
  bscore3 <- score.sentiment(x$cleaned_text,pos.words,neg.words,.progress='text')
  score3 <- as.integer(bscore3$score[[1]])
  return(score3)
}) -> result

result
```

Comment: Hey Ronak, thanks so much for your answer this worked perfectly!  Although I'm wondering how would I combine this with another loop? I have the form now where tss is now a list made from another by function, and when i try to do this it comes up as "Error in as.data.frame.default(data) : cannot coerce class ‘"by"’ to a data.frame"

Comment: You might need `result <- do.call(rbind, result)`